# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'make' in Flask web app

Tags: python, qr-code

I am trying to generate QR code in python. My code is working fine in another python file but throws an error when I tried to use it in Flask webapp.
I've already installed pillow and qrcode.

```
@app.route('/qr')
def qrcode():
   img = qrcode.make('https://youtube.com')
   img.save('first-image1.png')
   return 'all good'
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your debugging,

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function `qrcode()` refers to the local function, not to the external qrcode module/function/object. Your `qrcode()` function does not have any attribute named `make`, therefore an exception is raised. Here's an example:

```
def f():
    print(f.make)

>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'make'
```

To fix this, rename your function so that it does not clash with `qrcode`:

```
@app.route('/qr')
def qr():
   img = qrcode.make('https://youtube.com')
   img.save('first-image1.png')
   return 'all good'
```

Here I simply renamed your function to `qr()` so that it will no longer shadow `qrcode`.